# Create superblock for software raid-5 array

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, software-raid, mdadm, raid5

I have created a raid 5 array with mdadm. I created partitions on all five of the disks created a raid-5 array with mdadm on these five partitions).

Everything seems fine however when i try to mount the array i get a complaint about there being no superblock.

When i google for the solution all i get are hundereds of people trying to recover a defective array, all i need is a simple (at least i think it would be?) command to create this superblock (preferably without having to go through the 8 hour initialisation again).

edit:
The command used to create the array: (yes sdc is supposed to be left out)

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=5 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
```

The command used to partition the array:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0 -v -T largefile4 -m 0 -L Raid
```

The command with which i tried to mount the array:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/md0p1 /raid
```

Comment: The superblock should have been created when you created the array. This complaint may be a symptom of a deeper problem. What commands did you use to create the array? What is the complaint exactly (copy-paste)? Post the output of `mdadm -D /dev/md42` (or whatever the right number is).

Comment: I have added some information, will try mdadm -D tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to format the array before you can mount it, at the moment it's like a blank (single) disk.

eg: `mkfs.ext3 /dev/mdX`

Where mdX is your software RAID device, eg, `md0` or `md5`. Naturally you could use any file system you want on the device.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that. I did create a partition on the array.

Comment: You're getting confused between a file system and a partition, based on what you've added to the original question you're creating an EXT4 file system on the entire RAID device - your mount command should be `mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /raid`